# Suivre vs s’abonner

Tags: choix-de-mot

I was recently on twitter, where the follow button had suivre on. However, on Instagram, the same button was s’abonner. What is the difference between these terms as the English equivalent on both websites is follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, "S'abonner" is "to subscribe". It's a historical word, related to magazine and newspaper. "Suivre" is the literal translation of "to follow", French people use it on the internet since social network exists, but the first meaning of "suivre" is the same as in "to follow someone in the street", or in "to follow the path".

Comment: On irait même jusqu'à croire que les internautes sont des moutons.